# How to count words in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a list of lists like this: `[['Hello', 'Hi'], ["Hola", "Hi", "Ciao"], ["Ciao", "Hi"]]`.
What I want to do is to create a dictionary where the keys are every word from my list of lists and the values are the word count of words that appear only in the small lists where my key appeared.

**Desired output:**

```
dict = {'Hello': {'Hi':1}, 'Hi': {'Hello':1, 'Hola':1, 'Ciao':2},
        'Hola':{'Hi':1, 'Ciao':1}, 'Ciao':{'Hola':1, 'Hi':2}}
```

**Note:** I know how to use Python and how to deal with data structures, but I am struggling with
    the algorithm. I mean how many loops should I have and what my conditions should be?

Comment: why hello has "hi" with 2 as value whereas hola has "hi" with only 1? what is the logic here?

Comment: You want to leverage **collections.Counter** no doubt.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I apologize, I fixed that

Comment: Under what circumstances would the 1s become another value?

Comment: @Nick Sorry I did not get you. But the keys should be all the words I have. The values should be the count of other words that appear in the same list with the key. Hope I explained it in a good way

Comment: Maybe you could post an example input that would give the output that shows a value of 2 for the count?

Comment: @ShawnMehan Thanks! could you please show a small example!

Comment: I have a gut feeling on creating a graph from the input and then creating your above data structure from the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just one of your lists: `['Hello', 'Hi']`. This produces two "pairs" in your output `(Hi -> Hello)` and `(Hello -> Hi)`. To process one of the lists we're looking at something like:

```
for x in l:
    for y in l:
        if x != y:
           [update the count of x -> y]
```

(You could use `itertools.combinations` or `itertools.permutations` (depending on preference) to turn this into one loop.)

So how should we store the counts? As noted, the inner dictionaries are calling out to be instances of `Counter`, since it's basically a dictionary which defaults to 0 if the key is missing (meaning you don't have to check for the presence of the key, you can just increment the value). It would be convenient if your outer dictionary could be a dictionary that defaults to an empty Counter, which you can accomplish with `defaultdict`.

I'll leave it to you to write the code to update the counts and process all the lists, but hopefully this is enough to put you on the right path. (Both `defaultdict` and `Counter` are in `collections`. I initially found the `defaultdict` documentation kind of confusion--you'd create one with `counts = defaultdict(Counter)`.)

Comment: Thank you so much, that is really helpful. I got your first point of updating the count. But still not sure exactly how to parse all the lists that a specific word was mentioned in. I can create an outer loop to go through all the lists but when I check if `word in lists` it returns all the lists for me (basically because word is every word in my lists. Not sure if that make sense lol. Thanks again!